# Can you help figure out optimal way to code responsive section with multiple DIV's at multiple widths?

Tags: html, css, frontend

The attached photo is a design I'm trying to produce using html/css. It needs to be responsive, where the image and quote breaks under the left div. The main problem I'm having is figuring out how to produce the background effect where the text is outside.

I tried `position: relative, left: - 10px;` for the `<p>` tag and then did a media query to reset it on mobile. That worked (sort of) but I can't imagine it's the most efficient.

Any chance someone could try replicating the below mockup to show me how you'd do it?

Mockup I'm working with:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set image property

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

It automatically adjust with screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

For the main container, you could do something like this with CSS:

```
background: #cccbcb;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px #fff inset;
```

It doesn't really make the container smaller than its content, but it creates the illusion that it is without having to mess with positioning. Of course, you'll need a padding smaller than the `box-shadow`'s 50px (or whatever) for this to work (or just no padding at all).